# How to integrate facebook comments on individual posts on my blog

Tags: facebook, comments, integration

I have a problem with my facebook comment box on my blog. I am using a norwegian blog host so it is difficult for  n00b such as myself to get the instructions and where to put them in when it comes to hosts like blogger etc. Also english is my second language so I can get a lil bit confused when there's long instructions.. 
So, i just used the facebook comment box generator for "your website".. Anyhow.. The comment box appears, it works and that's great.. BUT, the same comment box appears on all of my posts.. And I have no ida how to sort out this mess to make them individual for each and every post...

It would be really great if ayone could help me on what tu stuff inn there or replace to make it work.

This is how the codes look like:

[image]

Hope someone can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

you will find it step by step in here ^^
http://jensontaylor.blogspot.com/2012/03/integrate-facebook-comments-for-blogger.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is very late to answer this question, but it will be helpful for others.
To solve this problem use  data-href="URL OF YOUR POST" in facebook comment div, here specify your each post url. this will show individual comment box for individual page.